# How to offer a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

I am not necessarily looking to do this right now, but I don't see how to offer a bounty on my question or another person's question. For future readers, I am currently at 636, so I should be fine as far as having enough rep.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You click on "start a bounty" on an eligible question.  From the [bounty FAQ on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work): "A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked."

[image: bounty]

As of this posting, your only [unanswered question](https://serverfault.com/questions/274007/how-do-you-reboot-a-server-when-you-are-not-local-to-it) is 1 day old, and not eligible yet.

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize you had to wait a day.

Comment: I also searched for help, but did not realize I had to go to a different, albeit related site.

Comment: @KCotreau: Welcome to the fun of FAQs on SE! There *used to* be a link from the SF [proper] FAQ to the MSO FAQ [which is where "they" really describe the *functionality* of the sites] but that seems to have been removed.  Of course the MSF FAQ doesn't detail *how* SE sites work, but rather, how the *SF community* is supposed to work.  Confused? I understand. Please try to bear with it for now, SF can be a lot of fun.  Eventually, you'll come to *know* which mess belongs to which pile.

Comment: Your comment made me giggle.